# Hide PyCharm's right-side gutter where the error stripes show?

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm has a thin right side gutter that shows little colored strips indicating the location of errors, TODOs, etc. in your code. I know you can change the error warning level to remove the error stripes, but how do you hide the entire gutter itself?

Likewise, how do you hide the little color square at the top of the right gutter which shows you code analysis status on hover?

Comment: You can't hide the gutter; what you can do is [disable inspections](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/disabling-inspections.html), but I am curious why you want to do this? The inspections and intents feature is one of the most powerful things in PyCharm (and other IDEs from Jetbrains).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- thanks, that's too bad. I like to have a "distraction free" mode that has a little visual clutter as possible. Yes the inspections can be very useful and I still want to be able to use the inspections when I want them.

Comment: Try searching the plugin repository, might be something there.

Answer (score 0):

If you click Hector, you can move the inspection level to None.  This turns off all the inspections (aka clutter) for the times you don't need them.

[image]